# Downloading ARC Lisp Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Tags: installation, lisp, arc-lisp

According to Paul Graham, first I'm supposed to

```
install version 372 of mzscheme
```

So I went here:
http://download.plt-scheme.org/mzscheme/mz-372-bin-i386-linux-ubuntu-sh.html

```
sh mz-372-bin-i386-linux-ubuntu.sh
```

But then when I download that shell script, and follow the instructions, I get the following error:

```
Checking the integrity of the binary archive... ok.
Unpacking into "/home/n/mz-tmp-install"... done.
mz-372-bin-i386-linux-ubuntu.sh: 478: mz-372-bin-i386-linux-ubuntu.sh: 
mz-tmp-install/bin/mzscheme: not found
Error: installation failed
(Removing installation files in /home/n/mz-tmp-install)
```

#### System info: Ubuntu 16.04.  64 bit

Comment: Don't vandalize your post to invalidate the present answers. Leave it as such. If you want to ask a new question, create a new separate post.

Comment: I was actually just trying to remove the irrelevant information for future users.  Imo, mzscheme is a distraction from Arc, which is the true beauty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to get that version of mzscheme working on your computer, but I can solve your higher-level problem of "how do I run Arc?"

The latest version of Arc, 3.1, [was released in 2009](http://arclanguage.org/item?id=10254). It no longer requires mzscheme 372 or earlier.

If you download [3.1](http://ycombinator.com/arc/arc3.1.tar), you can run Arc on top of Racket with `racket -f as.scm`. The install instructions on arclanguage.org have not been updated, however.

You might also want to look into [anarki](https://github.com/arclanguage/anarki/), a community-driven fork of Arc, which gets bugfixes and some changes. And [the Arc forum](http://arclanguage.org/forum) has a few people posting in it, if you have other questions.